# image saving in python (matplotlib)

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

In the code that I am working on, I have the following line:

```
    import pylab as pl
    pl.imsave(out_dir+'/'+fname.split('/')[-1],masked_im,vmin = 0, vmax = 1,cmap = 'gray')
```

However, I keep on getting the error that Bbox.from_bounds takes four arguments and I have given five. I've been looking at the Python scripts for pylab and I still can't seem to understand what may be causing this error.

Once I traced back the error, I arrived at this:

The Figure class within matplotlib has the following in the **init** function:

```
     self.bbox_inches = Bbox.from_bounds(0, 0, *figsize)
```

This seems to be causing the error. The image I'm trying to save is an array in the shape of (256, 256, 3). It's figure size is 256x256. In this case wouldn't from_bounds take four arguments ((0,0,256,256)). If not, what may be the fifth argument and how may it be fixed?

Comment: Can you give a complete example which fails?

Comment: I also suggest using using the os.path module for filename manipulation. The code will be more portable than explicitly using '/' as separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting cmap to 'rgb'? I looks to me as if you have an RGB image (256x256x3) but tell pylab to treat it as a grayscale image (256x256)